# Converting PCL to Tiff using Ghost PCl CreateAPIInstance returns -100

Tags: c#, ghostscript

Background: Trying to use GhostScript to convert PCL to Tiff. I am getting this error when trying to convert PCL to Tiff in a c# winforms application.

I am using Matthew's sample from https://github.com/mephraim/ghostscriptsharp.
This a cool wrapper that gives me access to the GS API.
But getting this error for some reason result is < 0:
Do I need to install GS on my computer? The sample already came with gsdll32.dll and gsdll64.dll.  I am trying to convert PCLToTiff. The sample has gsdll64 and does not include gpcl6dll6.dll.
Could this be the problem? Does gsdll64 encompass everything including PCL?
[image]

Here are the args.

[image]

I also tried it without the wrapper just by calling the executable. No luck yet.
I have the executable `gs9533w32.exe at C:\Users\tom\Desktop\GhostLib\gs9533w32.exe.`
I also have `newForm.PCl in the bin Debug folder of the application`.
I also tried using gpcl6win64.exe

[image]

Next trial:
Next question: If I were to buy a license for GhostPCL and integrate it as a part of the solution we provide, how would the install work? Is it as simple as putting the exe and DLL in a folder and just calling it from there or is there some installation involved?

Comment: Check the bin folder of your project and see gsdll is in the correct folder.

Comment: @jdweng: gsdll32 and gsdll64 are in the same folder as the executable of the windows application.

Comment: Is the date of the executable match the last time you did a build?

Comment: @jdweng: I am trying to convert PCLToTiff. Do I need gsdll64? I know there is a DLL called gpcl6dll64.dll and gpcl6win64.exe? I am not sure if these need to be used in the sample application. Or does gsdll64 encompass everything including PCL

Comment: Depending on the project settings (32 bit or 64 bit) determines if you need the 32 bit dll or the 64 bit dll.

Comment: @jdweng: I figured it out. see my answer. I was using the wrong dll import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to do a DLLImport for gpcl6dll6. The wrapper sample didn't have gpcl6dll6. It only had gsdll's

```
 [DllImport("gpcl6dll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_new_instance")]
    private static extern int CreateAPIInstance(out IntPtr pinstance, IntPtr caller_handle);

    [DllImport("gpcl6dll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_init_with_args")]
    private static extern int InitAPI(IntPtr instance, int argc, string[] argv);

    [DllImport("gpcl6dll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_exit")]
    private static extern int ExitAPI(IntPtr instance);

    [DllImport("gpcl6dll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_delete_instance")]
    private static extern void DeleteAPIInstance(IntPtr instance);
    #endregion
```